# Java Throttled "Consumer" Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, throttling

I'm trying to make a task queue that only runs once every `throttle` milliseconds while there are tasks in the queue. Also, because the tasks are making online queries I need to run them in a different thread to keep from slowing the rest of the application down. The data I'm getting isn't "high priority" and I don't need to run through the queue quickly, as much as I want to keep the request speed down to a trickle. I tried the following code despite being almost certain it wouldn't work:

```java
public class QueryManager implements Runnable {
    private Plugin p;
    private ScheduledExecutorService executor;
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<QueryRequest> jobs;

    public QueryManager(Plugin p) {
        this.p = p;
        this.executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        this.jobs = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        this.executor.schedule(
                this,
                p.getConfig().getInt("requestThrottle", 250), //the int is used as default
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    public void addJob(QueryRequest req) {
        this.jobs.add(req);
        this.notify();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        QueryRequest req = this.jobs.poll();
        if (req == null) {
            try {
                this.wait();
            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
        else {
            req.run();
        }
    }
}
```

As expected it results in an `IllegalMonitorStateException`. I'm not experienced with multithreading and have no clue how else to attempt my goal here. (Consumer is in quotations in the title because it acts kind of like one but I'm not sure if it is technically a consumer.)

Edit: By dropping `wait()` and `notify()` portions I was able to get it functional, but it doesn't meet my performance preference of pausing when there's no item in the queue.

```java
    //...snip...
    public void addJob(QueryRequest req) {
        this.jobs.add(req);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        QueryRequest req = this.jobs.poll();
        if (req != null) {
            req.run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the entire class?

Comment: @SamOrozco minus the pkg and imports that is the entire class.

Comment: this.wait() is your problem.  This is a typical problem for people just getting into Java multithreading.  I seriously recommend a solid review of good examples.  Learn it correctly now; avoid the hair-pulling later.

Comment: Why do you want to wait if there is nothing in the queue? Why not return out. Then try again in another 250 ms and see if there is something in the queue.

Comment: @SamOrozco I was able to get it functional and doing that exactly by dropping the wait and notify parts, but I'd prefer to make it pausable because the ```requestThrottle``` setting could be set much lower than 250ms and I don't want it running that frequently if it isn't doing anything. I'll update the question to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

What you *probably* really need is a [bulkhead](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/bulkhead), but to do this yourself, you just need to fix your `run` method to return immediately if you have no request waiting. It's the executor's job to call `run` repeatedly as scheduled.

Note that if you are managing your own executor, you should have a `shutdown()` method that shuts it down cleanly; in a container environment, that method should be annotated `@PreDestroy`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code was free of errors but would only execute a single job from the list:

```java
public class QueryManager implements Runnable {
    private Plugin p;
    private ScheduledExecutorService executor;
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<QueryRequest> jobs;

    public QueryManager(Plugin p) {
        this.p = p;
        this.executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        this.jobs = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        int throttle = Math.max(p.getConfig().getInt("requestThrottle", 250), 200);
        this.executor.schedule(this, throttle , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        Verbose.debug("Request throttle set to ", Integer.toString(throttle), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.name());
    }

    public void addJob(QueryRequest req) {
        this.jobs.add(req);
        Verbose.debug("Added query task to queue: ", req.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        QueryRequest req = this.jobs.poll();
        if (req != null) {
            Verbose.debug("Processing job...");
            req.run();
        }
    }
}
```

It still doesn't function however now that it has an entirely different problem I think it is best suited as an entirely different question. For some kind of continuity I'll edit in a link to that question once it's posted. Edit: New Question [Java "Throttled Consumer" Only Runs Once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626342/java-throttled-consumer-only-runs-once)